# ListView Border Color

Tags: android, listview, border, border-layout

Is it possible to create a `1px` width, colored border around a ListView?

I tried the following coding:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#BFFFFFFF" android:endColor="#BFFFFFFF" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:radius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

So... does anyone know how I can make a border line and set its color?

PS: I really searched for this issue in another posts and no success, that's why I created this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just add the `<stroke>` tag as shown below

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#BFFFFFFF" android:endColor="#BFFFFFFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#d8d8d8" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:radius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Please use 1dp instead of 1px and you can replace any border color as you wish for.